# Go from a frame to another frame located in another class

Tags: java, class, frame

I've got a class, and I want it to load a frame (created with the designer of NetBeans) located in another class. How should I be doing that?

```
public class Champs1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Champs1
 */
public Champs1() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("COMBAT SIMULATOR");
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
    setResizable(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 640, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 480, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Champs1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Champs1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Champs1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Champs1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Champs1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
// End of variables declaration
```

}

That's what I got on the class that holds the frame that I want to load.

Comment: Have you gone through the Swing tutorials including the [sections on how to use JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) yet? What part in this process are you stuck on? Do you understand how to create variables for referring to classes you've made?

Comment: No, I actually didn't, I just read some tutorials from there. Im gonna take a look ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I'll try:

First note that a frame in Java is a whole window, not only its content. So loading another frame would probably mean to open a new window. You can do this in Java like this:

```
new NameOfOtherFrameClass().setVisible(true);
```

I think things would get clearer if you read some tutorial and try to code something simple "by hand" (i.e. without NetBeans designer).

To get a better answer you should better explain what you mean by "loading" a frame or what you want to do and what your Java skills are.

Comment: My java skills are pretty basic, because I just started programming in java for a school project, and Im not really used to the way I should explain what I mean... And yeah, I think you're right when you say I should try to code something simpler, without using the NetBeans designer.

Comment: @Kevin04PT If you are new to java you should probably not start with GUI programming, this is not so easy in Java. I think it is best if you would start with writing something to `System.out`, loops (`for`, `while`), conditions (`if`)… I know the beginning is hard and maybe boring, but keep on learning the basics and Java will become fun! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call some another class's while you perform some action (for ex. while you click on a button). So, make some button or any other component and then implement `ActionListener`'s `actionPerformed()` method, in which you can specify the class's object and call the method from it.

**EDIT:**

for your reference:

```
JButton test_button=new JButton(new AbstractAction("Test") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Test test=new Test();            // Make Object of class which you want to call
                test.showMessage();              //Any method that you might want to call
            }
        });
```

Comment: And I actually have that. A button with an actionPerformed method, but I dont know what should i do to make it work... Im not sure I understood ....

Comment: @Kevin04PT: I've edited my answer, that might help you to understand